# World Map GUI from generated world

Tags: c#, user-interface, dictionary, render-to-texture, world-map

I have infinite generated world and now I need to make World UI Map similar to one in [Dont Starve](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/dont-starve-game/images/b/bc/World_Branch_Always.png/revision/latest?cb=20130329030747) or [7 Days to Die](http://7daystodie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Alpha_13_map.jpg).

I already creted this map, I know how to get data, how to get it into texture, how to make explored/unexplored area.

**My question & problem is, when player starts to scroll map to sides, it starts to lag, because I have to redraw the entire map texture (e.g. 512x512 pixels) each frame player scrolls/pans it.**

I ask just for general advice & idea. I am using c# & Unity, but dont think that is even imprtant for this issue, since I just need some pseudo code & idea.

Thanks for anyone who helps.

Comment: I don't know anything about Unity, but in the good ol' days, you would draw the outbounds of the texture before is seen. I mean,you have to draw not only the part of the map which can be seen,also the part surrounding it. I don't know if this is possible in Unity...

Comment: Hey thanks. Anything is possible in Unity, but as I said, I just needs some pseudo idea not related to unity or c#, as you have given me :D The problem is now that I draw bigger area, I have to draw to bigger texture, which takes even more time. But maybe that is the way to go

Comment: Well,it would take more time to initialize. After that,you just have to know which way your are moving and drawing only the offbounds part in that direction (and destroying the one left behind) I don't know if i'm explaining ok :)